# add a helper on the razor views (pagedList)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor, html-helper, pagedlist

i want to use the `pagedList` helper, i have a 4 layer aplication that has a `MVC4` has a presentation layer. i have added the librarys using `nuget`. then added the keys on the `web.conf` of the views like:

```
  <namespaces>
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
    <add namespace="JQueryUIHelpers" />
    <add namespace="PagedList" />
    <add namespace="PagedList.MVC" />        
  </namespaces>
```

the problem is thet when i try to use the helper (`@Html.PagedListPager`) is like it isnt loaded.

also try whit the clasic `@using` but i get the same result.
closed and reopen aplication and visual studio but nothing, any idea what else can i try?

Comment: You are an error or not ?

Comment: there is no error until i try to add the helper, the helpere isnt on the intelicense and if i handtype it i get an error of helper not defined method or extension

Comment: how did you install package with nugget ? (which command)

Comment: opened nugget UI, searched for pagedList.MVC and install

Answer (score 0):

I just had the exact same problem and the exact same error on

> `<add namespace="PagedList.MVC" />`

just replace it with

> `<add namespace="PagedList.Mvc" />`

Mvc not MVC with 'M' in upper case and both 'v' and 'c' in lower case.

Remember to restart visual studio.